# @RestController returns 404 not found except in main class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, kotlin, http-status-code-404

This is my project structure:

[image]

When I try to call this get API inside ApartmentController through postman I get a 404 error.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/apartment")
class ApartmentController(private val apartmentService: ApartmentService) {
  @GetMapping
  fun getAllApartments(apartment: Apartment): List<Apartment> {
      return apartmentService.getAllApartments()
  }

  @PostMapping
  fun createApartment(apartment: Apartment): Apartment {
      return apartmentService.createApartment(apartment)
  }
}
```

However, when I do the same thing inside my main class LeaderRealEstateApplication I get the 200 responses.

```java
@SpringBootApplication()
class LeaderRealEstateApiApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  runApplication<LeaderRealEstateApiApplication>(*args)
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/apartments")
class TestResource(private val apartmentService: ApartmentService) {
  @GetMapping
  fun test(): List<Apartment> {
      return apartmentService.getAllApartments()
  }
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've tried adding this to my `SpringBootApplication` annotation:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = ["com.leaderrealestate"])
```

Comment: Can you add the package statement of all your classes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your second approach, you have `@RequestMapping("/api/apartments")`, but in your first one you have `@RequestMapping("/api/apartment")`. Mind the extra `s` in the first `@RequestMapping`. If this is not a type in your question, this might be the reason for the 404.

Comment: No, I've added different names because spring upon boot tells me there is already a path with "/api/apartment" defined. So In postman I call "/api/apartments/" and I get the result and then remove the s and get the 404.

Comment: Understood, then can you add the package statement of all your classes? Thanks!